# How I can get the other part after a division with a modulo operator

Tags: matlab, division, modulo

When I divide 13 with 3 and use integer numbers the result will be 4.
With mod(13,3) I receive the remainder 1. But how can I get the 4 in Matlab? I think it is not possible to switch to integer numbers for this calculation, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `floor` function:

```
result = floor(13/3)
```

This function always rounds down to the lower integer

Comment: exact, and use fix() for rem()

Comment: Note however that results may be unconsistent when used with floating point parameters, for example `floor(0.3/0.1)*0.1+mod(0.3,0.1)`, partly because Matlab has special handling (rounding) when the quotient is near an integer...

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly use integers:

```
result = uint32(13)/unit32(3);
```

You can also use hex numbers:

```
result = 0xDu32 / 0x3u32;
```

Note that result will be of type `uint32`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`idivide`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/idivide.html):

```
result = idivide(13, 3);
```

You can specify the rounding method with a third argument, with the default being `'fix'`, or rounding towards zero. For example, this would round towards negative infinity:

```
result = idivide(13, 3, 'floor');
```